# How to get the type for a class by sending just the name of the class instead of the class itself as the parameter?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflection, dynamic

Dim a as Type=GetType(className) would gimme the type. But I have only the name of the class as string. I want something like GetType("class1") which would return the type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Type.GetType("class1")
```

Comment: @Peter, sure, but it's just what's asked. Far more important is that it only works for type defined in the mscorlib or in the assembly containing the call to Type.GetType.

Answer (score 1):

Both Type.GetType(...) and Assembly.GetType(...) expects a fully qualified type name. Thus, only passing in the class name without its namespace will not yield the Type.

If you make sure to include the namespace like this:

```
Type.GetType("Fully.Qualified.Namespace.class1")
```

will yield the same result as GetType(class1).

Update: if you don't know the namespace of your class, you could do a search (using Linq mind you) on types in the current assembly:

```
GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().First(type => type.Name == "AssemblyModuleTests")
```

I assume this is a slower operation than looking up types using fully qualified names since GetTypes() enumerates all types in the assembly.

Comment: You could combine the second query with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() to add scope to the search...

Comment: @Roger - surely. It would add even more to the burden though, since you would load all possible types in all loaded assemblies. So without knowing more about the scenario I wouldn't recommend it...