# Type manipulation

Tags: c#, types, casting

Is it possible to create a method which returns a type and use it?

for example, assume I have a Person type and Object parameter.
As you probably know, If we want to cast our Object parameter, we can write:

```
object param;

((Person)param).executePersonMethod();
```

My question is how can I write a method which return Person type and use it instead the concrete Person cast - I want write something like this:

```
public Type GetPersonType()
{
//return here type of person
}
```

and then use

```
  ((GetPersonType())param).executePersonMethod();
```

Is it possible?
If yes, how?

Comment: You may want to look at [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* execute methods on a `Type`, you *can* only execute methods on an instance of a particular `Type`. If I am understanding correctly, you should be able to use the **answer @LavG** gives to:

> return not the type but the object itself from the **GetPersonType** method

### **Edit:** As per your comment:

- Here are some SO QA which will help you get the `Type` using fully
  qualified namespace and other techniques:

[How to get the type for a class by sending just the name of the class instead of the class itself as the parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411372/how-to-get-the-type-for-a-class-by-sending-just-the-name-of-the-class-instead-of)

[Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

- Here is how to generate a class from the given Type at run time:

[generating a class dynamically from types that are fetched at runtime](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93322/generating-a-class-dynamically-from-types-that-are-fetched-at-runtime)

Answer (score 4):

You can use interface.

```
((IPerson)param).executePersonMethod();
```

each type of person must be an IPerson
and in IPerson you declare executePersonMethod()

Comment: Hi, I know this approach - it not good for my scenario, I need more dynamic solution. I don`t want create seperate Interface for any type

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) for this.

Note that using `dynamic` will skip any compile time checking whether that method exists and will throw an exception at runtime if it doesn't.

Due to this risk, I would only do this if I have no other choice, but it's good to know that the option exists:

```
dynamic d = param;
d.executeWhateverMethodHereWithoutCompileTimeChecking();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. There is a new type called dynamic which will avoid static type check during compilation.

```
public dynamic GetPersonOrObjectWhichHasExecutePersonMethod()
{
 //return not the type but the object itself
 return new Person(); 
}

public class Person
{
    public void executePersonMethod()
    {
      // do something
    }
}

// this is how you invoke it
public void ExecuteMethod()
{
  dynamic obj = GetPersonOrObjectWhichHasExecutePersonMethod();
  obj.executePersonMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like that:

```
Convert.ChangeType(param, typeof(Person));
```

It would returns param as a Person.

Answer (score 0):

Use

TypeOf()

Example :

```
        if (data.GetType() == typeof(Personne))
            return (Personne)data;
        else
            return new Personne();
```

After, check your object is not null to know if it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use Generic as a better option, however it is possible using Type Convertor in combination with reflection:

```
Type type = GetPersonType();
var converted = Convert.ChangeType(param, type);
converted
     .GetType()
     .GetMethod(/*your desired method name in accordance with appropriate bindings */)
     .Invoke(converted, /* your parameters go here */);
```